# unable to iterate large numbers in input

Tags: html

I have simple input box of type number with `step='0.01'`. I'd like to increase the current input value by the pre-defined step value using the up and down buttons situated on the very right side.
Now everything seems to work just fine while the number is less than or equals **13** digits. If it's greater it won't neither decrease nor increase the number by the step value. It just freezes the value not letting the user change the value using the up/down buttons.

```html
<input id="test" type="number" min="0.00" value="" placeholder="" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: Floating point numbers have limited precision. For example, in IEEE double precision, 1e15 + 0.01 is exactly equal to 1e15.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed this is only happening when dealing with decimal numbers. So is there any workaround?

Comment: Decimal or not is doesn't matter. 1e17 + 1 is exactly equal to 1e17. Floating point numbers have a limited precision; for example, an IEEE double precision number has 53 bits for the significand, giving a precision of a little less than 16 decimal digits. And anyway, *what use* do you have for greater precision? A precision of 1 part in 1e16 parts would allow you to measure the distance between the Earth and the Sun in thousands of a millimeter.